# google play services version issue real device

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-2.3-gingerbread

I´m new on android developement, and i have faced some troubles with google maps.
here are a few questions

I´know that adv with target 4.2 or higher includes google play services,
does this imply that real devices with lower versions will not run my app?

```
01-28 15:46:55.529: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(627): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4132500 but found 4131530
```

the lowest version for my app is 2.3 and it worked until i use gps and polilyne to draw routes between markers. I found a Google play services out of date Requires 4132500 found 4131530
if a device with android version 2.3 got google play services 4132500 will my app work fine?

if it so, with the next updated versions of google play services - will my app still work?

What can i do to make my app work fine on most devices as posible?

By the way, the app just work properly on bluestacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to include **google play services** library into your project and Maps v2 will run on all devices having 2.3 and above.

Note: Those device which do not support `google play services` or `glEsVersion version 0x00020000` will not be able to show maps. So, before loading map you must check that this device is supporting `google play services` or not. If not then you can show a message to user.

Comment: thanks, i´ve done some tests on real devices (2.3.4,2.3.6, and 4.1) and it work just fine.
Still have the same problems with every adv emulator i use, but now i´m sure the app works as i want in real devices.